# Using a batch file as a resource in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, file, batch-file

I have a batch file i want to create from my Resources.

I know this method for creating a file for .exe files:

```
byte [] resource_bytes = Project.Properties.Resources.exefile;
File.WriteAllBytes(path, resource_bytes);
```

It doesn't work the same for batch files.

Does someone has a solution?

Comment: Batch file is a simple text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A windows `Batch file (bat)` is a text file, Try this one:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    File.WriteAllText(resourcePath, text);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Batch file is empty");
}
```